# How to connect to a xampp server to a c# gui app?

Tags: c#, mysql, xampp

So i was trying to connect a c# gui app to a xampp sql server here's the code:

```
try
{

  string connectionString = "Server = localhost:8080; database = blog; Uid=root;Pwd";
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
  conn.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into logins(username,password) values('name','password')", conn);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

this is the code username is root and no password
but when the program starts it raises an exception saying:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 52.

Whats causing this problem and how can i solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: SQLConnection and SQLCommand are classes for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server. Your database server is MySQL. You can either try using the ODBC drivers built into ADO.NET, or use the extra Net/Connector library written by the MySQL folks: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: Ok...thanks for the suggestions i will look into it

Answer (score 0):

`SQLConnection` class is used to connect to `sqlserver` and to Connect Mysql `MySqlConnection` will be used
you need to add `MySql` Library in your `C#` project.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

## Config

```
string myConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=testDB;uid=root;pwd=pwd;";
```

## Use

```
string connetionString =""; //get from config;
MySqlConnection cnn ;
cnn = new MySqlConnection(connetionString);
```